In gitlab CI, how to specify IF NOT rules
I find it a bit difficult (and annoying) to use if:exists in gitlab ci, since lacking a NOT operator.
It seems like one should try to use only positive matches and combine with never, or on_success depending on the situation. I would like to have to write it only once and avoid duplications which NOT (or a "go through" operator) would allow
For example, with Psudo code:
jobA:
  rules:
    - if: cond1
      exists: my_file
      when: always
    - if: cond2
      exists: my_file
      when: on_success
    - if: cond3
      exists: my_file
      when: manual

I would like to have the exists clause only once, with for example notif -> never, or similar, like:
jobA:
  rules:
    - notif: #Not possible!?
      exist: my_file
      when: never
    - if: cond1
      when: always
    - if: cond2
      when: on_success
    - if: cond3
      when: manual

Is this possible? Or any suggestion to another solution.

did you try to use changes instead of exists ?
